# priority for test cases attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Trying to implement match function in XSL using TXE 2.0 specs for conflict resolution for template rules. Basically want to check the priority and wondering if for the below attributes I am doing anything wrong as I dont get results. Want to do the following in my match statements:

```
attribute(*, T) whose priority is 0
attribute(A, T) whose priority is 0.25
```

More on priorities: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict

Want my match statements to pass through the above 2 attributes so what changes should I make to help me achieve the result. so basically I want some test case that passes my match statements for above 2 attributes

My effort:

**Here is my XML:**

```
<CCC>ccc1</CCC>
<CCC attr2="1">ccc2</CCC>

 <XXX>XXX1</XXX>
 <XXX attr6="1">XXX10</XXX>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="attribute(*, CCCtype)">
    <match>CCC type: <xsl:value-of select="."/></match>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="attribute(attr6, XXXtype)">
    <match>attr 6 with XXX: <xsl:value-of select="."/></match>
 </xsl:template></xsl:template>
```

**schema:**

```
<xsd:element name="XXX" type="XXXtype"></xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="XXXtype">
<xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="attr6" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:extension>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:element name="CCC" type="CCCtype"></xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="CCCtype">
<xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="attr2" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:extension>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type in an `attribute(name, type)` pattern is the type *of the attribute*, whereas in your examples the `CCCtype` and `XXXtype` types are the types of the elements that the attributes belong to.  For "any attribute of an element of type `CCCtype`" you'd need

```
element(*, CCCtype)/@*
```

and for "the `attr6` attribute on any element whose type is `XXXtype`

```
element(*, XXXtype)/@attr6
```

Both of these patterns have the same default priority, but they couldn't match the same nodes anyway as there's no inheritance relation between the two types - an element can't be both `CCCtype` and `XXXtype` at the same time.

And finally it goes without saying that this will require a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon-EE.

Comment: In my XSL, I am already checking for element but want some match statements which follow attributes(*, T) & attribute(A,T) what changes to make? `attribute(attr6, xsl:string)` ??

Comment: @fscore it'd be `xs` or `xsd` rather than `xsl` (whatever prefix you've mapped `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` to in your stylesheet) but yes, the second argument is the type of the attribute itself.

Comment: how will schema-element(E) be implemented?

Comment: @fscore it means the element `E` as declared globally in the schema (i.e. not just any element named `E`, but specifically uses of such an element that correspond to a top-level `<xs:element name="E">` in the schema) or any other element that is declared to belong to E's [substitution group](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-equivalenceClass).